# How to perform functions on each cell containing 1x17 cells in itself?

Tags: matlab, function, cell, cell-array

I have a nested cell array 'y2a' of size 1x128 with each cell containing cell array of size 1x17.

For eg: y2a{1,1} is a 1x17 cell array.Similarly y2a{1,2} and so on.

I have to multiply the data in each sub-cell array (ie; y2a{1,1} or y2a{1,2}...etc)using the following formula

```
  for cells 1-7 
   S=(celldata)*(2^(7-i))
  for cells 8-16
   S=(celldata)*(2^(7-i))
```

where 'i' is the position of the cell.Since there are only 17 subcells and  use only 16 of them the value of i varies between (1,16).

Each nested cell in y2a has a 1 bit binary number as its data.

I want to perform the above function for all the nested cells present in each y2a. 
I tried the following code for performing this

```
   Y=y2a{1,1}
   for j=1:1:7
       S1(1,j)=(Y(1,j))*(2^(7-j))
   end
   for k=8:1:16
       S2(1,k)=(Y(1,k)*(2^7-k))     
    end
```

This seems to work out for one cell, but for doing this for all the cells i'm having trouble in forming the for loop.How should i do it in matlab?

Comment: Who giveth thee this ugly data structure for binary representations of fixed point numbers?

Comment: Have you considered a `cat(1,y2a{:})`?

Comment: @knedlsepp it just converts the original array of size 1x128 into 128x1 array

Comment: You have demonstrated that you know how to access the contents of a cell array in matlab, and you already have the pseudocode---where's the roadblock in translating that into matlab code?

Comment: @Rosh191: In fact it should make it a nice `128-by-17` cell, which would make for an even nicer `128-by-17` array, if you applied `cell2mat`.

Comment: @knedlsepp   yep, ugly, and also *incredibly* inefficient.

Comment: @knedlsepp can you please elaborate? I'm new to matlab and i'm quite slow in understanding things.

Comment: I'll go with *jez*: What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: @knedlsepp i edited my question and included the code i had tried..

Comment: @Rosh191: Well just put a for loop `i` from 1 to 128 around this and use `(i,j)` instead of `(1,j)` and `(i,k)` instead of `(1,k)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the nested cell array into a 2Dmatrix first by using the following code

```
A = reshape(cell2mat([y2a{:}]),[],numel(y2a)).';
```

You could as well look at the below link for i too had asked a similar thing
[How to separate data from nested cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198635/how-to-separate-data-from-nested-cells)

Then perform the required action using

```
B=num2cell(A);%convert it into a 2D matrix of size 128x17

for i3=1:1:128
for j = 1:1:7
S1{i3,j} = (B{i3,j})*(2^(7-j))
end
end

for i4=1:1:128
for k = 8:1:16
S2{i4,k} = (B{i4,k})*(2^(k-7))
end
end
```

you'll probably get the output

Comment: So you asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198635/how-to-separate-data-from-nested-cells) in order to answer this one? By the way: the first line of code could be done simpler via: `A = cell2mat(cat(1,y2a{:}))`.

Comment: @knedlsepp i had the same doubt involving nested cells...and he didnt get any answers...so i thought i could ask the basic one, because the latter part can be coded by anyone...