# How to separate data from nested cells?

Tags: arrays, matlab, nested, cell, cell-array

I have a nested cell as given below

```
A= {1x12 cell}  {1x12 cell}  {1x12 cell}  {1x12 cell}  {1x12 cell}
```

I had tried A{:} for getting the data in the above cells and I obtain it as below

```
ans = 

 Columns 1 through 12

'1'    '0'    '1'    '0'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '1'    '1'    '1'    '1'    '1'



 ans = 

 Columns 1 through 12

'1'    '1'    '0'    '1'    '1'    '1'    '1'    '0'    '1'    '1'    '0'    '0'




 ans = 

 Columns 1 through 12

'0'    '1'    '1'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '1'    '1'    '0'    '0'




 ans = 

  Columns 1 through 12

'1'    '1'    '1'    '1'    '0'    '1'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '1'




  ans = 

  Columns 1 through 12

'0'    '0'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '1'    '0'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '0'    '1'
```

I want to have the binary data inside each cell in separate vectors stored in variables. My desired output is as follows,

```
  a1=[1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    ]

  a2=[1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    ]

  a3=[0    1    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    ]

  a4=[1    1    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    ]

  a5=[0    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    1    ]
```

How to achieve such a result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if tomorrow you end up with `100s` of such cells, then you would have `a1`, `a2` ... `a100`. Ever thought that way?

Comment: What would be the most efficent way to perform a simple function such as multiplication or an XOR operation on nested cells like the above?

Comment: I thought separating the nested cells might be somewhat okay if i need to perform functions on the data available on the cells..

Comment: Well my point was to keep the workspace *more organised* as a general idea and not specific to this problem. And my hinted suggestion was to use a 2D array given the consistent sizes of the expected output arrays.

Comment: @Divakar i tried using the cell2mat function but then it just renders me the array of size 5x1.

Comment: @Divakar I think I stole your idea (hadn't read the comments), sorry!

Comment: @LuisMendo Oh no it's great actually, hoping OP follows it!

Comment: @Divakar Yes, I'm too lazy to explain it unless absolutely necessary

Comment: @Divakar and LuisMendo thanks a lot...i do get it... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better use a matrix (as suggested by Divakar):

```
M = reshape(cell2mat([A{:}]),[],numel(A)).';
```

Or more simply, as noted by knedlsepp:

```
M = cell2mat(cat(1,A{:}));
```

Then your desired "variables" are the rows of `M`, that is, `M(1,:)`, `M(2,:)` etc.

Comment: Thank u so much...i had used the for loop and was not able to execute the code properly...understood it...

Comment: @AbiramiAnbalagan Glad about it!

Comment: Alternatively with less transposing: `M = cell2mat(cat(1,A{:}))`.

Comment: @knedlsepp Well seen! Edited